# incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[100]’

Tags: c

Script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char inn[100];

int main()
{

    inn='EEE';

    if(strcmp(inn,"EEE") == 0){
    printf("ok");
    }

}
```

Compile Error:

```
gcc test.c -o test

test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:9: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     inn='EEE';
         ^
test.c:9:8: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[100]’ from type ‘int’
     inn='EEE';
```

What is the solution ?

Should I change my top declaration or should I do something differently elsewhere ?

Comment: The delimiters `'` and '`' around some value denotes the value as a character constant. But a character constant can only consist of 1 character. The remainder is ignored or flagged as a warning.

Comment: 1) Arrays cannot be assigned, 2) string literals need to use `"`, not `'`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

single quotes are invalid in C for string. They can only be used for single char.

To set "EEE" string to inn variable, use strcpy function:

`strcpy(inn, "EEE");`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char inn[100];
int main() {
    //In C, you have to manually copy string
    strcpy(inn, "EEE"); 
    if (strcmp(inn,"EEE") == 0){
        printf("ok");
    }
}
```

Remember to include `string.h` library too.

Comment: ...or use `char inn[100]={"EEE"};`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie this is in case of initialization. Can be just char inn[100] = "EEE"; but this was not question he acked I suppose.

Comment: changed to double quotes. and placed **strcpy(inn, "EEE");** right under **inn="EEE";**  warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’ [enabled by default]
     strcpy(inn, "EEE");

Comment: include "string.h" and will work. inn="EEE" is invalid in any case.

Comment: copy and pasted the whole stuff. :  test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’ [enabled by default]
     strcpy(inn, "EEE");

Comment: You did not include string.h library. I have updated my answer already.